# URL masking to external URL using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have a question I would like to redirect my URL and mask the external URL to my URL for example.

ExampleA.com is my URL
ExampleB.com is the External URL.

What I want is when users type `ExampleA.com` it should pull out `ExampleB.com` content, but on the address bar it should have `ExampleA.com` URL appearing.  So far I have done this but its not working it pulls out the content of `ExampleB.com` but it still shows `ExampleB.com` on the address bar. Please see below for the code I have done.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ExampleA.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://ExampleB.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: There's obviously no way to make a browser load `https://ExampleB.com` when the user types `https://ExampleA.com`. And I think that's good because when the user loads his bank site he wouldn't be amused to be actually connecting to some phishing site. You'll have to configure Apache to act as proxy or reconsider why you want to do this in the first place.

Comment: A company that we are partnered with they have created me a website, but they have something else in the middle to my domain name, but I have my own domain name and people know my domain name because I used have my own website. See example below what I mean.

[mydomainname.com] (I own, no content)
[external.domainname.com] (partner created website with content)

what I want is when people type [mydomainname.com], I want it to show the content of [external.domainname.com], but on the browser address bar I want people to see [mydomainname.com] instead of the [external.domainname.com]

Comment: try replacing `[L,R=301]` with `[P]`

Comment: I did do that but its still showing up the partners url once I'm on the website.